# Handsontable not scrollable on IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, handsontable

I am working with handsontable and I need it to fill the space of its container, as we can't manually set the size of the table when we create it in this particular project. It works fine with Firefox and Chrome but on IE the scrollbar disappears and the mouse scroll doesn't work either.

I made a fiddle where the issue happens: http://jsfiddle.net/Knuk/12dpct1b/

Here's the structure of the HTML:

```
<div class="table-container">
    <div class="table-handsontable">
        <div id="table" class="hot handsontable htRowHeaders htColumnHeaders">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content1">
        Content 1
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content2">
    Content 2
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.table-container {
    display: block;
    height: 338px;
    width: 338px;
    position: relative;
}

.table-handsontable {
    overflow: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 54px; 

    width: 100%;
}
```

The content boxes need to stay at the same location.

So far I was able to make a workaround where if the browser is IE, it renders all the rows, otherwise it acts the same way as it did before. The scroll CSS is also set to auto. Link: http://jsfiddle.net/Knuk/12dpct1b/18/

Visually it works, but in the background it loads all the data, which can be rather heavy for IE if the table is too big. Is there something I'm doing wrong, or a better workaround I could use?